# Frame set for hundreds of HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, frameset

I want to create a parent page which will hold the table of contents, navigation buttons, and header footer . In the content part it will show HTML pages as and when clicked from the table of content or navigated through the navigation button.

I understand that frameset is one of the options but how do I use it to link those hundreds of HTML pages?
My doubts -
what should be the starting point? 
Where should I put the link of those hundred HTML pages?
Can I make it read the files from a folder directly instead of manually writing the list?

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scandir` on the parent folder and loop through the results and output them as links.

Comment: Yes I have access to php but will it work inside a zipped scorm package??